# Placing one figure per page in appendix of figures

Tags: floats

I would like to place one figure per page in my appendix of figures.

Currently I do this with

```
{\centering

\vfill
\includegraphics[]{Appendix/S1.pdf}
\captionof{figure}{caption}
\label{S1}
\vfill
}
```

I can fit about two per page.  Most of these will have lengthy captions, and so I will need to do one per page.  How can I place the figure dead centre with one figure per page?

Comment: Centering is the default behavior.  Take out the `\vfill` commands and make sure you have `\begin{figure}[p]`.

Comment: Just put a `\clearpage` after/before each figure.

Answer (score 2):

While vertical centering is the default for `[p]`. it does not guarantee only one figure per page.  Also, `\vfill` does nothing unless the height is previously set.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}% MWE tools
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[p]
\parbox[c][\textheight][c]{\textwidth}%
{\centering
\includegraphics[]{example-image}
\caption{\blindtext}
\label{S1}
}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```